# How do I download a file from google drive using v3 rest api?

Tags: qt, google-drive-api, qt5

**My Objective:** To download a sqlite file from google drive using google drive v3 rest api

I am working on project that involves downloading a sqlite file which is stored in google drive. So far I have been in successfull in authorizing and getting the access token. I also had luck getting all the file names (sqlite files) stored in the google drive with their respective file id. Now I want to download the file using the file id. I followed the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/get), and send the request with file id. But all i am getting is

```
{
 "kind": "drive#file",
 "id": "1AmaXWbtmkvihy1g9yoYSSCssgL4fVh6t",
 "name": "_db.sqlite",
 "mimeType": "application/octet-stream"
}
```

This is my code:

```
bool File_Control::Download_File(const QString &FileName)
{
    // Get FileID
    QString FileID = m_Map.value(FileName, QString());
    if(FileID.isEmpty()){
        emit setMessage("Fatal Error: FileID is missing for FileName");
        return false;
    }

    qDebug()<<"File ID "<<FileID;

    // Now Prepare the request
    QUrl url(tr("https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/%1").arg(FileID));
    QUrlQuery query;
    query.addQueryItem("alt","media");
    url.setQuery(query.query());


    QNetworkRequest request(url);
    QString headerData = "Bearer " + m_Settings->get_Google_Drive_Settings
            (Google_Drive::AccessTokenEnum);
    request.setRawHeader("Authorization", headerData.toLocal8Bit());

    QNetworkReply *reply = m_Account->get_Request(request); 

    // Now wait for the response
    QTime t1 = QTime::currentTime().addMSecs(TIMEOUT);
    while((t1>QTime::currentTime()) && (!reply->isFinished())){
        QCoreApplication::processEvents();
    }

    if(reply->isFinished())
    {
        if(reply->error() != QNetworkReply::NoError){
            emit setMessage("Error: "+reply->errorString());
            delete reply;
            return false;
        }
        else{
            QByteArray array = reply->readAll();
            qDebug()<<array<<reply->error();
            delete reply;
            return true;
        }
    }
    else{
        emit setMessage("Error: Timeout");
        delete reply;
        return false;
    }

}
```

Am I missing something?

Edit 1:
**m_Map** -> QMap that stores file names (of files from drive) as key and file id as value.
**m_Settings** -> A helper object that helps in getting access_token which is stored in Windows Registry
**Google_Drive** -> A helper enum type.
**m_Account** -> Object that helps in authorising google account. This object contains my QNetworkManager so i made a function called get_Request to get my "get request"

Comment: Please, provide details about `m_Map`, `m_Settings`, `Google_Drive` and `m_Account`.

Comment: @scopchanov please check my edit. Thanks!

Comment: I have seen the edit, but without them the code can't be comipled, so the issue cannot be reproduced.

Comment: @scopchanov I just thought of checking the size of QByteArrray array that i read into, and surrprisingly it is as the original file in drive. The fault was, that I was debugging the array to console, so qt dint show the data on console. Problem solved!

Comment: @scopchanov thanks for your time :)

Comment: The magic of posting :) I am glad you've solved the issue. Please post the solution as an answer.

Comment: @scopchanov Answer posted! Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Initially I din't set the `alt` to `media`, so that explains the reponse I have got in the first place. Then I have set the value as shown in the code.

The issue was, that I was trying to see the contents of *QByteArray* in the debugging console. Since the array contains binary data, Qt did not show any characters and I thought that Google has sent an empty packet.

To make the matter worse, I have read this [guide](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-downloads) and tried to reproduce it in my browser. So I have got the error code 400.

Eventually, I have thought about checking the size of the array and to my surprise it was the same as the size of the original file on the drive. Then I have saved the contents of the array to a local file and checked the SQLite file and everything was OK.